# Destructor in Constructor in c++?

Tags: c++

I am coding a ticket Reservation System I was just planning to how to code it
The problem which I am confronting is a little bit tricky. My Requirements are:

- A bus consists of only 100 bookings at a time.
- if exceeded more than 100 then no booking may reserve.

Now the problem I am facing is I am not getting a logic not to book a ticket for a passenger when the limit is exceeded. And shift its reservation to the next bus automatically.

Here is the code which I have done till yet.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class BUS {
int SOD = 6;
int EOD = 22;
int capacity=0;
int BUS_NO;
public:
BUS(int no) :BUS_NO(no) {
    if (capacity == 100) {
        cout << "Capacity is Full\n";
        return;
    }
    else {
            if (capacity != 100) 
                capacity++;
    }
}
int bus_No() { return BUS_NO; }
void routes() {
    cout << "=========================================\n";
    cout << "1.Saddar " << "2.Marrir Chowk\n";
    cout << "3.Liaquat Bagh " << "4.Committe Chowk\n";
    cout << "5.waris Chowk " << "6.Chandni Chowk\n";
    cout << "7.Rehman " << "8.6th Road\n";
    cout << "9.Shamsabad " << "10.Faizabad\n";
    cout << "11.Pothar " << "12.Khayan e Johar\n";
    cout << "11.Pothar " << "12.Khayan e Johar\n";
    cout << "13.Faiz Ahmad Road " << "14.Kashmir Highway\n";
    cout << "15.Chaman " << "16.Ibn e Sina\n";
    cout << "=========================================\n";
}
void reserveTicket() {
    if (capacity != 100) capacity++;
    else cout << "Wait for Next Bus plzz! This is full.\n";
}
};
class PASSENG {

};
```

Comment: Why are you checking `capacity` in the `BUS` constructor? Won't it just always be `0` at that time?

Comment: How you're deciding the number of buses, Is there any limitation on the number of buses and?

Answer (score 1):

During writing this answer, I am considering that we have an infinite number of buses available.
Now we have 3 functions.

1.`ticket_book(int n)` => This function will book tickets for the number of passengers we want. If the number of passengers increases then automatically it will book the ticket on the next available bus.

2.`get_bus_capacity()` => This function will return currently available seats in current bus.
3.`get_bus_number()` => This function will return the current bus number.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class BUS {
int SOD = 6;
int EOD = 22;
int capacity=0;
int BUS_NO = 1;
public:
void book_ticket(int n)
{
    if(capacity + n <= 100)
    {
        capacity += n;
    }
    else
    {
        int cur_bus_seat = 100 - capacity;
        int next_bus_seat = capacity + n - 100;
        capacity = next_bus_seat;
        BUS_NO += 1;
    }
}
int get_bus_capacity()
{
    return 100 - capacity;
}
int get_bus_no()
{
    return BUS_NO;
}
void routes() {
    cout << "=========================================\n";
    cout << "1.Saddar " << "2.Marrir Chowk\n";
    cout << "3.Liaquat Bagh " << "4.Committe Chowk\n";
    cout << "5.waris Chowk " << "6.Chandni Chowk\n";
    cout << "7.Rehman " << "8.6th Road\n";
    cout << "9.Shamsabad " << "10.Faizabad\n";
    cout << "11.Pothar " << "12.Khayan e Johar\n";
    cout << "11.Pothar " << "12.Khayan e Johar\n";
    cout << "13.Faiz Ahmad Road " << "14.Kashmir Highway\n";
    cout << "15.Chaman " << "16.Ibn e Sina\n";
    cout << "=========================================\n";
}
};
class PASSENG {

};


int main()
{
    BUS bus;
    int n;
    
    while(1)
    {
        int choice;
        cout<<"Enter Your Choice"<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter 1 to book ticket"<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter 2 to check number of seats"<<"\n";
        cout<<"Enter 3 to check Bus No"<<"\n";
        cin>>choice;
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the number of tickets to be booked";
            cin>>n;
            bus.book_ticket(n);
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            cout<<bus.get_bus_capacity()<<"\n";
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            cout<<bus.get_bus_no()<<"\n";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```